# Need the full path of the file being uploaded in telerik mvc upload control

Tags: model-view-controller, upload, telerik, filepath

In my project I need to access the full path of the file being uploaded and show as tooltip when I hover my mouse over the file being uploaded.

In the image below you can see the tool tip which shows only the name of the file and not its full path.

I am not able to get the file path either in client side or server side. Is it possible to get the file path in any of the client events ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the onSelect method.

```
function onSelect() {
        var files = arguments[0].files;
        if (files && files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var src = e.target.result;
                var alt = files[0].name);

                //This is where the magic happens
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0].rawFile);
        }
    }
```

This example code is used for a single file upload.

The src will be Base64 which can be used as a src for an img tag.